# How to fix "There is no server listening on port 9876" error while running karma?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, karma-runner

I am running the following:

```
PS D:\app> karma run
```

It shows the error:

```
[2013-11-29 17:39:54.297] [DEBUG] config - Loading config D:\app\karma.conf.js
There is no server listening on port 9876
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

They changed the delivery model for Karma recently

To install Karma itself, as you have already done:

```
npm install karma -g
```

But then you need to install drivers for testing frameworks. For example for QUnit

```
npm install karma-qunit --save-dev
```

Next you have to install launchers for the different browsers. For example Chrome and IE

```
npm install karma-ie-launcher --save-dev
npm install karma-chrome-launcher --save-dev
```

And now you should be good to go.

Now simply launch karma by using the start command with the config file as an input

```
karma start path/to/tests/karma.conf.js
```

Comment: Also be sure to have all the browsers installed!

Answer (score 36):

You should use `karma start` command to execute karma test suite from command line.

Comment: Original poster is probably running it from grunt with grunt plugin, although impossible to guess from the description. So command line is not viable.

Comment: @psp I created this answer after I googled this exact message. Just wrote here what helped me. It obviously helped more people. As you mentioned, Grunt usage is just a guess.

Comment: See this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27602746/) on how to automatically start the karma server from within grunt.

Comment: `karma run` is another alternative.