# Getting karma server to launch upon grunt watch

Tags: gruntjs, karma-runner, grunt-contrib-watch

While developing, I'm using karma and grunt to watch for file changes and run the tests.

In command line, I'd like to be able to simply enter

```
$ grunt watch
```

and have the karma server to start once, and thereafter having grunt watching for changes and running the various tasks (including karma tests) whenever files change. I don't want to enter `$ karma start` .

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Option #1

One can use the `atBegin` option of `grunt-contrib-watch`. The idea is to introduce a startup task, which will run at the startup of the watcher:

```
watch: {
    startup: {
        files: [], // This is redundant, but we get an error if not specifying files.
        tasks: [ 'karma:continuous:start' ],
        options: {
            atBegin: true,
            spawn: false
        }
    },

    ...
}
```

The full `Gruntfile.js`:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        karma: {
            options: {
                files:      [ 'client/**/*.spec.js' ],
                frameworks: [ 'jasmine'   ],
                reporters:  [ 'progress'  ],
                browsers:   [ 'PhantomJS' ],
                singleRun:  true,
                autoWatch:  false
            },
            continuous: {
                singleRun:  false,
                background: true
            }
        },

        concat: { ... },

        uglify: { ... },

        watch: {
            startup: {
                files: [], // This is redundant, but we get an error if not specifying files.
                tasks: [ 'karma:continuous:start' ],
                options: {
                    atBegin: true,
                    spawn: false
                }
            },

            js: {
                files: [ '<%= concat.js.src %>' ],
                tasks: [ 'concat:js', 'uglify' ]
            },

            karma: {
                files: [ '<%= concat.js.src %>', 'src/**/test/**/*.js' ],
                tasks: [ 'karma:continuous:run' ]
            },

        }
    });

    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    grunt.registerTask( 'default', [ 'concat', 'uglify', 'karma:unit:run' ] );
};
```

## Option #2

As shown in [this](http://blog.credera.com/technology-insights/java/testing-angularjs-part-3-karma-grunt/) and [this](http://jorshasaur.us/unit-testing-with-angular-part-1/) blogs, an alternative is instead of calling

```
$ grunt watch
```

one creates another task that launch the karma server:

```
grunt.registerTask( 'serve', [ 'karma:continuous:start', 'watch' ] );
```

and then calls:

```
$ grunt serve
```

The full `Gruntfile.js`:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        karma: {
            options: {
                configFile: 'karma.conf.js'
            },
            unit: {
                singleRun: true
            },
            continuous: {
                // keep karma running in the background
                background: true
            }
        },

        concat: { ... },

        uglify: { ... },

        watch: {   
            js: {
                files: [ '<%= concat.js.src %>' ],
                tasks: [ 'concat:js', 'uglify' ]
            },

            karma: {
                files: [ '<%= concat.js.src %>', 'src/**/test/**/*.js' ],
                tasks: [ 'karma:continuous:run' ]
            },

        }
    });

    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    grunt.registerTask( 'default', [ 'concat', 'uglify', 'karma:unit:run' ] );

    grunt.registerTask( 'serve', [ 'karma:continuous:start', 'watch' ] );
};
```

Comment: I should avoid comments like "thanks", but... thanks!!